# what's the best way to specify datatypes in pandas read_sql?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, types, sqldatatypes

If i use `pandas.read_csv()` I can specify the datatypes and use converters to convert them to the types I want, but when reading data from SQL with `read_sql()`, there's no way I can do this. I can see in Github it's still an open request from users.

When use `read_sql`, one column is `float64` type, how can I convert it to `decimal` type?

Comment: date format is str. How do you plan to convert that to int64? as epoch timestamp?

Comment: @Shiva After second thought, I think it's probably better to leave it as `str`, how about converting from `float64` to `decimal`?

Comment: By `decimal` do you mean Python's `decimal`(`from decimal import Decimal`)? pandas doesn't have a `decimal` datatype.

Comment: yes `from decimal import Decimal`, if I read from a csv file, I can specify the columns to be `Decimal` and then use `converters=` parameter in `read_csv()`, but for `read_sql()` there's no such converter parameter to do so.

Comment: You can try [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html): `df['my_col'] = df.my_col.apply(lambda x: Decimal(x))`

Comment: `float64` sounds like MySQL's `DOUBLE`.

Comment: Does that mean there's no way we can specify datatypes when using `read_sql`? We'll have to read the data first and then specify the datatypes?